# Is there a class provide function of StackFrame.java in android?

Tags: java, android, stack-frame

I know com.sun.jdi.StackFrame could provide the ability to access the local variable and parameters of a suspended thread. And I wonder is there a same function in Android?

Comment: Could you explain as to why you want to do this? There may be a more preferred way in Android.

Comment: Since I need want to scan through the application memory variable, I want to get all the variable including local variable. I know that it is possible to do that on jdk but I could not find any way on android.

Answer (score 0):

Following Android.dev documentation

> http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html
>
> **StackTraceElement[]**
>
> **getStackTrace()** Returns an array of
>   StackTraceElement representing the current thread's stack.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html

Comment: Those method could get the information of stack trace, but I want a way to get the local variable on the stack, which is not provided by those methods.